# How can I add an i++ statement before editing a discord message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically, I'm trying to change what day's weather the bot is displaying on a reaction. I want to i++ on reaction but nothing seems to work.

I'm still quite new to javascript, let alone discord.js so hopefully it will be more obvious to you guys.

````js
.then(sentEmbed => {
  sentEmbed.react("⬅️"),
    sentEmbed.react("➡️")
  const filterLeft = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '⬅️' && user.id === author;
  const filterRight = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '➡️' && user.id === author;
  const collectorLeft = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filterLeft, {
    time: 15000
  });
  const collectorRight = sentEmbed.createReactionCollector(filterRight, {
    time: 15000
  });

  collectorLeft.on('collect', r => sentEmbed.edit({
    embed: {
      color: 3449993,
      title: "Edit worked",
      thumbnail: {
        url: 'https://i.imgur.com/HX79Nk6.png',
      },
      fields: [{
          name: "Date",
          value: dates[i],
          inline: true
        },
        {
          name: "Temperature",
          value: temps[i],
          inline: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }))
  //                collectorLeft.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
  collectorRight.on('collect', r => client.channels.cache.get(channel).send(`Collected ${r.emoji.name}`));
  //               collectorRight.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));

  client.channels.cache.get(channel).send(author)

})```
````

Comment: What does "I'm trying to `i++` on reaction" even mean? What are you trying to do? Keep a tally of "reactions"? Totally need more info.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean but if you want to add 1 to `i` every time it collects a reaction, you can just do `i++` whenever it collects something:

On a seperate note, you don't need to collect 2 reaction collectors, you can just add more emojis to your filter. Read [the reaction collector section](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) of the discord.js guide for more info.